# Task.WhenAll() - does it create a new thread?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have completed.

When Task.WhenAll() is called, it creates a task but does that necessarily mean that it creates a new thread to execute that task? For example, how many threads are created in this console application below?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task RunAsync()
    {

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Task<string> google = GetString("http://www.google.com");
        Task<string> microsoft = GetString("http://www.microsoft.com");
        Task<string> lifehacker = GetString("http://www.lifehacker.com");
        Task<string> engadget = GetString("http://www.engadget.com");

        await Task.WhenAll(google, microsoft, lifehacker, engadget);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetString(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`WhenAll` does not create a new thread. A "task" does not necessarily imply a thread; there are two types of tasks: "event" tasks (e.g., `TaskCompletionSource`) and "code" tasks (e.g., `Task.Run`). `WhenAll` is an event-style task, so it does not represent code. If you're new to `async`, I recommend starting with my [introductory blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Your test application will use thread pool threads and IOCP threads as necessary to finish the `async` methods, so it may run with as few as 2 threads or as many as 5. If you're curious about how exactly the threading works, you can check out my [recent blog post on `async` threads](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: That linked post is really nice. You made me a believer ;)

Comment: For someone possibly trying to figure out why there are thread pool threads involved in OP's code, he explains here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237250/will-httpclient-async-methods-run-in-new-threads