# Will HttpClient Async methods run in new threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpclient

I'm wondering whether .Net `HttpClient` `async` method run in new threads or in the main one.

For example, In my Console Application, I invoke an `async` method to download a URL content using `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` method.

Will this method (GetStringAsync) run in new separate thread?

Comment: I'd suggest you to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419572/5311735 and answer to the end. In short - you cannot tell exactly without inspecting source code (or unless it's mentioned in documentaiton).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, asynchronous I/O methods do not use separate threads. I explain this in detail in my blog post [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

However, *in this specific case*, that's not quite true. `WebRequest`-based APIs in .NET have supported asynchronous operations for a long time, but have actually always done HTTP proxy detection and DNS lookup as *synchronous*, even through their asynchronous APIs. This was noticed when `HttpClient` started becoming popular. Unfortunately, Microsoft decided *not* to fix these long-standing bugs.

So, `HttpClient` wraps its `WebRequest` calls in a thread pool thread. Note that it is still using the "asynchronous" APIs, so only the synchronous portion (HTTP proxy and DNS lookup) are done on a thread pool thread; the rest of the request is truly asynchronous. At least, this is true for *some* platforms.

Comment: I was looking at this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/mt674882.aspx . Luckily, there was HttpClient example. In that link, there is a section called Thread and they mentioned that no extra threads will be created within async-await context. Do you think that section is not related to the example?

Comment: `The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created.` - that statement is perfectly true. Neither `async` nor `await` create new threads.

Comment: @StephenCleary - I'm surprised to hear .NET's own `GetStringAsync` actually IS NOT truly asynchronous... is it at least safe to assume most other .NET methods with `Async` in the name are truly asynchronous and not making threads? Such as File.WriteAsync.

Comment: @mmcrae: No. For `File` in particular, the I/O is not asynchronous unless an async flag is passed to the constructor.

Comment: @StephenCleary sounds like async IO is not as enabled as I thought. I guess I am very surprised since I understood from your posts and others that most IO at least on Windows is truly async (no thread). And discussions saying to use async with all of the `...Async` methods in .NET. I thought a big point of `async / await` was to get access to the true asynchronous behavior that already exists through the framework and the hardware.

Comment: @mmcrae: Asynchronous Win32 APIs are all truly asynchronous. In the .NET world, it's not as clean. There's some weird quirks that can't be fixed due to backcompat (e.g., `HttpClient`), and other weird quirks due to OOP (e.g., what's the "correct" implementation of `MemoryStream.ReadAsync`?), and other weird quirks for AFAIK no good reason (e.g., `File` async I/O requiring a special flag to be truly asynchronous).

Answer (score 0):

No. Because using async / await is mainly created to accomplish IO-bound tasks asynchronously not creating new threads. Only with CPU bound tasks new threads are created.

Comment: Any links on proofs of this statement?

Comment: Programming in C# Exam Ref 70-483

Comment: @DigheadsFerke page?

Comment: Page 17: Asynchronous code solves this problem. Instead of blocking your thread until the I/O operation finishes, you get back a Task object that represents the result of the asynchronous operation. By setting a continuation on this Task, you can continue when the I/O is done. In the meantime, your thread is available for other work. When the I/O operation finishes, Windows notifies the runtime and the continuation Task is scheduled on the thread pool.

Comment: Page 19: So doing a CPU-bound task is different from an I/O-bound task. CPU-bound tasks always use some thread to execute their work. An asynchronous I/O-bound task doesn’t use a thread until the I/O is finished.